# Bootstrap modal getting disappeared Immediately Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have added bootstrap modal to show entries information in it, but I am facing an issue, the modal is getting disappeared within a second, I don't know what's wrong, as I checked the same question on different forums, many developers suggest to remove the JS files, but I am using WordPress and not sure which .js file making issue and how to remove it for specific pages.

More Info: It was working fine before activating the UsersWP plugin, that plugin is not useful on the profile page where I am facing this issue, but it is useful on other parts of the site, can anyone help to remove js files added by that specific plugin from profile pages only.

Modal Code:

```
                            <?php
                                
                                $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "offers";
                                $author = get_the_author( 'ID' );
    // this will get the data from your table
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" . " WHERE author=" . "'" . $author . "'");
            foreach($retrieve_data as $list){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $list->first_name . " " . $list->last_name . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $list->email . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $list->post_title . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $list->purchase_price . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $list->purchase_type . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $list->closing_date . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal" .  esc_html($list->id) . "'" . " data-whatever='@getbootstrap'>View Details</a></td>"; ?>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo esc_html($list->id);?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Offer Details Submitted by: <?php echo esc_html($list->first_name . " " . $list->last_name);?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h4 class="col-md-12">
                    Propery: <?php echo $list->post_title; ?>
                </h4>
          <h3 class="col-md-12">
                    Contact Information:
                </h3>
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="font-weight-bold">Agent's Full Name:</span> <?php echo $list->first_name . " " . $list->last_name; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <span class="font-weight-bold">Agent Email:</span> <?php echo $list->email; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Agent Cell Phone Number: <?php echo $list->phone; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Agent's Brokerage Name: <?php echo $list->brokerage_name; ?>
          </div><div class="mt-1">
          </div>
          
          <h3 class="col-md-12 head-mar">
                    Offer Details:
                </h3>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Purchase Price: <?php echo "$" . $list->purchase_price; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Purchase Type: <?php echo $list->purchase_type; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Lender Name: <?php echo $list->lender_name; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Name of Loan Officer: <?php echo $list->name_loan_officer; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Name of Loan Officer: <?php echo $list->phone_loan_officer; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Email of Loan Officer: <?php echo $list->email_loan_officer; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Closing Date: <?php echo $list->closing_date; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Concessions Amount: <?php echo "$" . $list->concessions_amount; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Inspection Period: <?php echo $list->inspection_period; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Occupany: <?php echo $list->seller_occupancy; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Earnest Money Deposit: <?php echo "$" . $list->emd; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Home Warranty: <?php echo $list->home_warranty; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Additional Terms: <?php echo $list->additional_terms; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <ul>
              <?php
                $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "offers_attachment";
                $author = get_the_author( 'ID' );
                $offer_id = $list->id;
    // this will get the data from your table
    $attach_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" . " WHERE author=" . "'" . $author . "'" . " AND offer_id=" . $offer_id);
            foreach($attach_data as $attach){
         echo "<li>" . $attach->url . "</li>";
            }
             ?>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div></div></div></div>

<script>
  $( '#exampleModal<?php echo esc_html($list->id);?>' ).click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    $( 'exampleModal<?php echo esc_html($list->id);?>' ).modal();
  )};
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

I checked source code and found this:

```
<script src='https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/userswp/vendor/ayecode/wp-ayecode-ui/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>
```

I try to remove it for a specific page by reading some StackOverflow questions but it's still there.

Code putted in child theme's functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() 
 { 
    if ( is_page('my-account') ) 
      {
        wp_deregister_script( 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js' ); 
      } 
 }
```

Comment: Ask plugin dev for the best way to deregister or add compability with other plugin/theme

Comment: Please try $('#elemetID').modal('show');, your code has missing parameter "show"

Comment: @DebasisRath thanks, I added 'show' but still facing same issue.

Comment: `$( 'exampleModal<?php` missing class or id

Comment: you have added **e.preventDefault();**, and tried to show the dialogue manually, but it will show automatically when you click the anchor for it. 
remove the manual trigger :: "$( '#exampleModal<?php echo esc_html($list->id);?>..."
check more here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/